# What elements of Arkham Horror balance the difficulty across the number of players?

Tags: arkham-horror

I know the number of open gates that triggers the awakening of the Ancient One reduces as the number of players increase, and the number of roaming monsters in Arkham increases as well, so there is the crowdedness factor that seems more perilous. Also, there are two monsters per gate opening when there are 5+ investigators. Are there other factors? These factors don't seem as significant or maybe as linearly ramped as the balancing factors in Eldritch Horror where clues, gates, surges, and mystery requirements scale with every 2 added investigators.

Comment: The extra monsters are a pretty big deal when going from four to five players, which is a pretty common real life scenario.

Comment: Ha, I initially read this as having to deal with monsters in real life as being a real life scenario. So this sounds like 4 may be a potentially optimum number of investigators.

Comment: It's certainly a lot easier than 5. (Playing with a lot of players also just makes the game incredibly long and inefficient, unless you have enough disciplined players. I've been dragged into an 8 player game where people whose turn was a ways off completely stopped paying attention to the game, and the only thing that kept it going was me saying, hey, it's your turn.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'limits' that change with more players are:

1. Maximum number of monsters on the board before they go into outskirts
2. Maximum number of monsters in the outskirts before the terror track is moved
3. Maximum number of gates that can be open at any time
4. Maximum number of monsters that trigger the awakening of the Great Old One once the terror level has reached 10

Comment: Do you mean the terror track for item 2? Also while this does seem a value that's tweaked for balance, it's probably clearer to simply say that there is only ever 11 monsters allowed in the game board and the truly game-affecting aspect here is how many get returned when that 11 monster game limit is reached.

Comment: @Joey I suppose you can think of it that way, but sure seems to me like the truly game-affecting thing is the presence of additional monsters on the board.